# Is the word 'places' an 'adverb of place'?

Tags: nouns, adverbs

Please may I ask if the word 'places' is considered an 'adverb of place'? Here is a sentence example:

> The dog takes his bone places.

I have a student who has asked this question. As far as I know, the noun 'place' is not considered part of the 'adverbs of place' list. I have searched far and wide to make sure I am correct, but cannot find a definitive answer.

Comment: It can hardly be both a noun and an adverb, now can it? They are different word classes (parts of speech). It's a noun and its function is adjunct of place; in this case an informal way of saying "The dog takes his bone to places.

Comment: I'd normally expect ***places*** here to be introduced by a preposition *(**to**)*, but that feels like just a stylistic choice. Don't ask me why we ***have*** to include some such preposition before ***work*** used in the same context, but we ***can't*** include a preposition if *the dog takes his bone **home***. They all *(**places, to work, home**)* look like "adverbial" elements to me.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for your comment. Regarding 'place' not being able to be both a noun and an adverb, do you mean to say, in this sentence example specifically, that 'places' cannot be both a noun and an adverb? I know there are some words that are both nouns and adverbs - for example the word 'tomorrow' can be an 'adverb of time'. I am just wondering if 'place' is ever considered an adverb? Thank you!

Comment: It's important to distinguish word class (part of speech) and function. POS are noun, verb, adjective, adverb, preposition etc, while functions are subject, object, complement modifier etc. In your example "places" is a noun functioning as a modifier (in this case a locative adjunct). When you talk of 'adverb', I suspect you are talking of 'adjunct', which is often called 'adverbial'. Compare "We had breakfast in bed", where "in bed" is a preposition phrase (category) and "in bed" is an adjunct (or adverbial) functioning as a modifier.  Does that clear things up?

Comment: Is this sentence found in the text of a well-known author or is it  in a student's writing?

Comment: @BillJ Thank you so much for this explanation. I now understand and see my error in mixing up adverb and adverbial meanings and functions. I really appreciate your time and for pointing this out!

Comment: @LPH This sentence is from a children's picture book. To be honest, I am not sure the author of the book. The student only sent the text to me.

Comment: That makes unlikely then the possibility of a confusion induced by the idiom "to be going places" or of some pun based on that same idiom.

Comment: The **to** is elided: The dog took the bone [to] places. My father used to take my mother [to] places, now he doesn't. There one can see that places is a noun. This is also seen in utterances like this: He's a guy who's going [to] places.

Comment: There's no elision of "to" in "He's a guy who is going places". It has nothing to do with going to places, but means that he is showing talent or ability and is likely to be a success. It's quite different to "The dog takes his bone places".

Comment: The analysis here depends on how POS is determined (and despite claims to the contrary, not all academics agree on this at all points). 'He's going places' (more commonly seen than your example) obviously uses _places_ (informallly) in a way that adds information to the verb. Traditionally, some analysts called this usage (apparently pressing a noun into adverb duty; other examples are  'Yesterday I came a different way' /  'Let's go some place', the latter again informal) examples of _adverbial objectives_. Aarts looks at various lumping / gradience / splitting models of 'problem words'.

Comment: I disagree on two counts: (1) It doesn't use "places" informally. "Going places" is an **idiom**  meaning 'showing talent or ability and is likely to be a success'. (2) It's not 'pressing a noun into adverb duty', though you probably meant 'adverbial' duty (the term adjunct is better). Idioms often resists conventional analyses, and this is no exception.     "Places" would have to be analysed in a tree as a noun, but as I said, there's no elision of "to". Of course, it's an odd construction, but that's what you get with idioms.

Comment: Let's say that we find seeming informality at the origin of the term: "to be more and more successful in life or career", therefore "moving or going from place to place of greater interest" (and similar wording  with basic constructs using "place" ( more or less figuratively)), thereby a practical recourse to informality (or better, ungrammaticality) that is soon seen as a means of convenient semantic coding  and individuation ("going to places of little interest", for instance, is not parasited) and a rapid loss in informality that is realized in the full consecration as an idiom.

Answer (score -2):

It depends of context and its, hm, placement in sentence)

You see, there is a word 'place', which can be noun in single form ('a place, the place'), noun in plural form ('places') and also it can be a verb. Verb, in its turn, can be used with nouns of first or second ('We place the new rug on the porch') and third person ('He places keys in his backpack')
So to determine you just need to check - is a word 'place' **a verb** or **a noun**.

Let's take your example - "The dog takes his bone places'. Let analyze word by word:

- the dog - okay, it's our main subject, it is a noun word;
- takes - aha, its our subject's action, third person form, simple tense - so, it's 'take', done by third person - the dog;
- his bone places - well, looks like it's a subject of noun action, it can't be the verb - so it's a noun.

Looks like in current sentence context 'bone places' - it's a couple or multiple holes, done by dog for hiding its bones.

Comment: Or it could be a simple elision of *to* as part of a prepositional phrase: *The dog takes his bone (to) places.*